# StackOverFlow Error while validating the project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Hi I'm facing an error message while eclipse is validating the project. I have tried to clean the project but it didn't worked at all.

Also I have increased the heap size from `eclipse.ini` file but still getting the same error. Below the eclipse.ini file is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1G
-Xmx3G
```

also I have checked the logs from `.metadata\.logs` it seems like I have deadlock somewhere.Here it is.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-03-05 16:09:37.164
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Validating PolicyServices".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.DeadlockDetector.indexOf(DeadlockDetector.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.DeadlockDetector.lockAcquired(DeadlockDetector.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.LockManager.addLockThread(LockManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.OrderedLock.setCurrentOperationThread(OrderedLock.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.OrderedLock.attempt(OrderedLock.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.OrderedLock.createSemaphore(OrderedLock.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.OrderedLock.acquire(OrderedLock.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.OrderedLock.acquire(OrderedLock.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.releaseFromRead(ModelManagerImpl.java:1920)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.releaseFromRead(ModelManagerImpl.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.AbstractStructuredModel.releaseFromRead(AbstractStructuredModel.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.releaseFromRead(DOMModelImpl.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.document.DOMStyleModelImpl.releaseFromRead(DOMStyleModelImpl.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.context.resolver.structureddocument.internal.impl.WorkspaceContextResolver.getPath(WorkspaceContextResolver.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.context.resolver.structureddocument.internal.impl.WorkspaceContextResolver.getProject(WorkspaceContextResolver.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.ui.internal.contentassist.MyModelQueryExtension.getAvailableElementContent(MyModelQueryExtension.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.internal.modelqueryimpl.ModelQueryExtensionManagerImpl.filterAvailableElementContent(ModelQueryExtensionManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.ModelQueryImpl.getAvailableContent(ModelQueryImpl.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.modelquery.HTMLModelQueryImpl.getAvailableContent(HTMLModelQueryImpl.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.validate.HTMLElementContentValidator.validateNode(HTMLElementContentValidator.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.validate.HTMLElementContentValidator.validateContent(HTMLElementContentValidator.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.validate.HTMLElementContentValidator.validate(HTMLElementContentValidator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.wst.html.core.internal.validate.CompositeValidator.validate(CompositeValidator.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.propagateToChildElements(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validate.AbstractPropagatingValidator.validate(AbstractPropagatingValidator.java:40)
```

Can someone please let me know how can I remove the deadlock? So that I can proceed further. Because without validating the project the workspace is not building properly. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `-Xss512K` to your `eclipse.ini`, please

Comment: @RAnders00 at what location ? after the Xmx ?

Comment: Just on its own new line at the end of the file

Comment: @RAnders00 okay give me a try with it.

Comment: what about the deadlock ? which are already acquired ?

Comment: @RAnders00 still getting the same error message.

Comment: We need more of the stack, enough to show where it's recursively looping. The version of Eclipse would be good, too, especially if it's not the latest (in which case, retry it with the latest).